# how to send stream to multiple peers in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, multipeer-connectivity

is there a way to pass an array of `[self.session connectedPeers]` into the stream method to achieve simultaneous audio streams to multiple listeners?
I am using `TDAudioPlayer` and `TDAudioStreamer` in my project.
Please help